# Which number of update my VS2013 is running?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

I have been searching here and there on the internet about which visual studio 2013 update I am running on my pc for longtime.

I viewed the About Visual Studio info in the "help" menu of vs.
It gives the framework version and IDE versions i.e 4.5 and 12 respectively.

I also checked the registry just for a hit and trial to get the info but couldn't get any regarding the update.

So how to check that I am using update 2 or 3 or 4 or whatever.

Edit: The update version is not written in the "About"

Comment: This is not a question for SO.

Comment: I regret that questions are judged according to the symbols.
Anyways, Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my installation it tells me in the top left hand corner of the Help/About dialog. You might want to take another look.

[image]

If you don't have it shown there it might suggest that you don't have any update installed.

Also if you look at "Tools/Extensions and Updates..." then switch to the "Updates (n)" tab on the left you should find the latest Visual Studio update listed under the Product Updates section.

Comment: Why downvote?
I made a lengthy research then asked the question.